# Rewriting URl containing GUID as query string C#

Tags: c#

I'm currently working on a project that require a lot of rewrites

The current urls include guid and look like this:

```
  http://localhost:88/en-GB/search/?country=f8c889dd-6c8c-4623-8304-17e575c6b5f5&c360=&postcode=&distance=&m=&model=20d6bcfd-409f-49d7-8692-4cb423105c7e&b=&der=&tra=&col=&maxm=&maxp=&d=&maxage=
```

I would like to achieve something like this:

```
  http://localhost:88/uk/bosch/...
```

I can't map all the combinations in the web.config (needs to stay under the 250kb); a code solution, library might help

Thank you

IIS 7

.net 3.5

sql azure

visual studio 2013

tried mapping all combos

```
<urlrewritingnet rewriteOnlyVirtualUrls="true" contextItemsPrefix="QueryString" defaultPage="default.aspx" defaultProvider="RegEx" xmlns="http://www.urlrewriting.net/schemas/config/2006/07">
<rewrites>
   <add name="SearchResults2" virtualUrl="^~/(en-GB)/uk/?$" rewriteUrlParameter="ExcludeFromClientQueryString" destinationUrl="~/_search.aspx?_identifier=search/&amp;_locale=$1&amp;c=7309d34a-d467-48dc-8324-9a9c9856c486" ignoreCase="true" />
```

...............

they seem to work but can't have them all (thousands and thousands) on the live site web.config too big

I could get a map of each code to the string equivalent from db

Comment: In wich version of asp.net are you working on ? Please provide more informations on your environment

Comment: Have you tried anything? Is there a table that maps the Guids to country codes / model names?

Comment: If they are in a database, make a 404 handler that will check if the URL is found and redirect or give the actual error page based on that.